# Change my compass orientation so it points to the south

Tags: java, android

I have a `MainActivity` class where I created a custom compass. The compass is pointing to the north.

But, I want to set the compass pointing to the south (or any other direction)

Which value of my code do I have to change so the compass is pointing always to the south?

Here is the code:

> MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    mPointer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.linkID);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mMagnetometer);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor == mAccelerometer) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mLastAccelerometer, 0, event.values.length);
        mLastAccelerometerSet = true;
    } else if (event.sensor == mMagnetometer) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mLastMagnetometer, 0, event.values.length);
        mLastMagnetometerSet = true;
    }


    if (mLastAccelerometerSet && mLastMagnetometerSet) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mR, null, mLastAccelerometer, mLastMagnetometer);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(mR, mOrientation);

        float azimuthInRadians = mOrientation[0];
        float azimuthInDegress = (float)(Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadians)+360)%360;


        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
                mCurrentDegree,
                -azimuthInDegress,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f);

        ra.setDuration(250);

        ra.setFillAfter(true);

        mPointer.startAnimation(ra);
        mCurrentDegree = -azimuthInDegress;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Try changing `azimuthInDegress`. It might give the desired result. Also, where did you get the code from? If you got it online, there might be some explanation at the same place.

Comment: Do you mean this line of code? `float azimuthInDegress = (float)(Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadians)+360)%360;` is form the internet but no explanatios where I took it from :/

Comment: What I think is that that line calculates the amount of degrees which is then used to decide in what direction the compass should point at. I think that if you add a line like `azimuthInDegress = (azimuthInDegress + 180) % 360`, the compass will always be turned 180 dergrees, making it point south instead of north. However, it's just a theory which you'll have to test ;)